# Front page url permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am working on a website and got stuck to an issue, whenever I access website.com it redirects me to http://website.com/continent/asia/ and I don't know why.

This is a custom post type called continent, and the Asia is set in WP settings as the front page. Why does my homepage show /continent/asia in url and not just www.website.com ? The .htaccess files is okay.

If I assign other page as homepage the url is clean www.website.com, if I assign any continent (CPT) the url gets the /continent/asia .

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It seems that some plugin is doing this, how did you create the CPT?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to settings> general> and make sure the wordpress address(URL) and the Site Adress(URL) is set to http://website.com/ and not http://website.com/continent/asia/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the general settings are http://website.com/ I checked the options table in Database and it's also website.com it's **not** website.com/continent/asia

Comment: A work around it would be: You can always create a custom template in your theme file, Then create a page and then assign that page as the front page. IN the custom template you can assign one specific category to that page: query_posts('cat=80'); (80 will be the category)